# Symfony 2.7 add more property FOSUser and got error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

I have got this error when run command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Before I also add more property for User entity class

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>     [Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\Entity" in class TL\UserBundle\Entity\User was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Please help me about that.
Thanks

Comment: As @lemairep said, that's a really simple thing.
Maybe you should learn more about programming before you proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Tan Do you check what the error message propose ?

In your entity UserBundle\Entity\User do you have something like this :

```
<?php

namespace xxxxBundle\Entity\xxx;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * xxx
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="xxx")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="xxxxBundle\Entity\xxx\xxxRepository")
 */
class xxx
{
```

If you don't have the line

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

it's normal that Doctrin complain ...

Comment: Hi @lemairep, Thanks for your helping. It's working for me now.